# Rudin 'Functional analysis' problem with theorem 5.25

Tags: functional-analysis

I read proof of theorem 5.25 and I don't understand  this fragment:

'If we now define $\mu(E)=L_{\chi(E)}$ ... '

What is $L_{\chi(E)}$ ?

Comment: More context would help - the surrounding paragraph and later usage of $L_{\chi(E)}$.

Comment: 'If $G$ is an abelian group and $\mathcal{M}$ is power set of $G$ then there is a function $\mu: \mathcal{M}\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\mu$ is 'finitely addictive', $\mu(E+a)=\mu(A)$ and $\mu(G)=1$'.  $L$ is an extension (from Hahn-Banach theorem) of some function defined on $l^{\infty}(G)$. Then we define $\mu(E)$ as $L_{\chi(E)}$

Comment: Edit: $\mu(E+a)=\mu(E)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably $L(\chi_E)$, where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic/indicator function of the set $E$, i.e. $\chi_E (x)=1$ for $x \in E$ and $\chi_E (x)= 0$ otherwise.

Comment: $L$ is defined on $l^{\infty}(G)$, so $\chi_E$ can not be an argument of $L$ ( $\chi_E$ is defined on $2^G$, not on $G$).

Comment: The characteristic function $\chi_E$ **is** defined on $G$, namely $$\chi_E : G \to \{0,1\} \subset \Bbb{R} \subset \Bbb{C}, x \mapsto \begin{cases}
1, & x\in E,\\
0, & x\notin E.
\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Ok, my mistake, thanks.